# Adding Fields via Ajax Blackhole

Tags: cakephp

I have a form which updates multiple records in a table and is working fine. I want too be able to add new records via ajax am loading the following in via ajax but am getting blackholed

```
<?
$uuid = String::uuid();
?>

<tr>
    <?=$this->Form->input('Attachment.'.$uuid.'.id',array());?>
    <?$this->Form->unlockField('Attachment.'.$uuid.'.id');?>
    <td><?=$this->Form->input('Attachment.'.$uuid.'.title',array('label'=>false,'style'=>'float:left;'));?></td>
    <?$this->Form->unlockField('Attachment.'.$uuid.'.title');?>
    <td><?=$this->Form->input('Attachment.'.$uuid.'.url',array('label'=>false,'style'=>'float:left;'));?> <button onclick="return false;" class="btn attachment_select_file" style="float:left;"><i class="icon-folder-open"></button></i></td>
    <?$this->Form->unlockField('Attachment.'.$uuid.'.url');?>
    <td><button class="btn"><i class="icon-trash icon-large"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"There may be cases where you want to disable all security checks for an action (ex. ajax request). You may “unlock” these actions by listing them in $this->Security->unlockedActions in your beforeFilter." - from [The cook book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-security-component-for-specific-actions)

The first thing I'd be doing is disabling the security component completely and seeing if that fixes it. If it does, then re-enable the security component, and add the relevant action to

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions
```

in your beforeFilter.